# Magento 2 Enterprise Multistore - Speed Optimization

Tags: optimization, magento2, pagespeed, cloud-hosting, multistore

Recently I have completed migration from M1 to M2. Total of 5 stores reside under single Magento 2 installation in the Cloud now. Page speed is a pain point at this time. Lighthouse and web.dev scans suggesting several areas to be improved, such as bundling JS and reducing JS execution time, as well as minimizing main-thread work. Installed Amasty Page Speed Optimization extension, but it barely made an impact. Installed Magepack JS Bundling tool, and it did make small difference, however still need to get the websites optimized to improve the performance. Can anyone suggest another extension or recommend effective steps to get the sites optimized?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say why your website is slow with limited information.

But you may try following.

1. Check if site is running in production mode.
2. All the caches are enabled.
3. Disable all the custom modules and check if it runs fast with default Magento code?
4. Try to enable Magento profiler and investigate which code/event etc. is taking more time.
5. Check Magento logs and Server logs to see if there are any errors or connection timeouts to any third party services.

Once you have some kind of report with which you can identify what is causing slowness. You may decide next course of action.

Comment: Hi Mukesh, thank you for your response, your insight is much appreciated. We constantly scan the sites with Lighthouse, web dev tool, and gt metrix, and scan reports pinpoint the culprits pretty accurately. Slow Time to Interactive, high Speed index, Total Blocking Time metric is high, etc. That is why we have to rely on Magento extension to help with some degree of performance optimization.